# Used Ctrl-Alt-F6 in Linux, and can't get my screen back

Tags: linux, console

This is obviously a stupid question.
I am coding in Eclipse both on Mac and Linux, but I mixed up and used the Mac shortcut to window tabbing (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>), but I was using the Linux on uni and screen went black. I've done this before, but this time I can't get back to my desktop. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> gives me different terminals, <kbd>F7</kbd> gives me a black screen and <kbd>F8</kbd> a blinking underscore in the top left corner. Shouldn't my session have been somewhere in <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> and is it lost?

Comment: I dont think it was a stupid question. Its OK not to know the nuances of an unfamiliar OS.

Comment: I clicked `ctrl`-`alt`-`f6` by accident today and had no idea how to get back.  Your *question* saved me: `ctrl`-`alt`-`f1` to return to X-Windows.  *phew*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

X is probably still running on <kbd>F7</kbd>, your display driver (or something else) is just misbehaving. You might be able to trick it into coming back on by going to <kbd>F7</kbd> and blindly opening a terminal and playing with xset ($ *xset dpms force on*). Or you can <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>backspace</kbd> to kill X and GDM should restart it.

Try seeing if you can repeat the problem and then file a bug report (or let the lab admin know if it isn't your computer). It probably has something to do with your distro's kernel configuration/patching. I've had this happen before on Ubuntu but not any other distros (I've used many), which is why I am assuming it might be distro-specific issue. Probably the unintended consequences of some kernel patching.

Comment: It was a really annoying bug, so i'm not going to recreate it today at least:P Maybe i'll do it tomorrow. Thanks for a nice answer.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue. I tried with hitting ctl+ alt + F1 together. And it worked

Answer (score 15):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> should work perhaps your X has crashed?

I just did what you did and <kbd>F7</kbd> got it back for me, saying that before I remember X crashing and I had the same black screen

Comment: That may be, but the vt that gets assigned to a local X session is distribution-dependent.

Comment: The fact that Ctrl-Alt-F7 doesn't give him a blinking cursor indicates that is the VT assigned to X.  Is it possible a blank screen-saver has kicked in?  Hit a few keys when you are in VT7.

Answer (score 5):

The <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> (x=1..6) key combinations often allow you to have up to 6 concurrent terminal sessions on the console. 
Usually one is setup to use X windows, and differs from distribution to distribution. Typically its on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

http://linux.about.com/od/linux101/l/blnewbie5_1.htm

Some distributions of Linux allow you to kill the X Windows session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> at which point the operating system will attempt to restart it.

Answer (score 5):

```
alt + F1
```

works for ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I just experienced this. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 but alt + F1 seems to refresh the black screen. Ctrl + alt + F1 took me back to my initial screen lol.

Comment: Funcionó para mi

Answer (score 4):

In the future, you can go into a terminal and type:

```
init 3
```

To bring the system into text mode, and:

```
init 5
```

To return the system to X mode. The nice thing about doing it that way is that everything should be shut down and restarted cleanly.

Answer (score 3):

For My case. I tried with hitting

> ctl+ alt + F2

together. And it worked in Fedora

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd>. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like X crashed. To check, you could log in on one of the terminals (on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> etc.) and check that the "X" process is still running.

I've had the same happen to me recently, and found the SIGSEGV and backtrace later in /var/log/Xorg.0.log. Curse your graphics driver vendor (usually) and then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

We're running gnome on Red Hat 5.
ps axu in one of the other terminals showed some of the processes still running. Probably something with the display drivers then. Did <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>backspace</kbd> and restarted it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

F8 solves the problem in Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa

Comment: Sorry, Ctrl+Alt+F8 not just F8